# Magento 2: Checkout page is loading very slow

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout-page

The checkout page on our Magento 2 store is loading insanely slow. Does anyone know what causes this or how to fix this?

Customers are cancelling the orders in this last step. Really frustrating.

Thanks a lot!

## UPDATE:

I provided a screenshot of the chrome waterfall. As you can see, some files are queued at 8+ seconds. Some files take over 30 seconds to load.

How can we speed this up? I checked the TTFB by enabling profiling, but that didn't show any significantly slow things. Please check screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried caching, JS AND CSS merge?  Please share website URL and server configuration(ram, PHP version, Mysql version).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. The checkout page shows the loading spinner for about 1 to 2 minutes and then loads the checkout form.

Comment: Pleas, provide more details like your website url and which modules are installed for checkout, have you tried after disable one by one?

Comment: Maybe the screenshot helps @kunj
I think the server config is ok. There's only one site running on a pretty good server.

Comment: I have a very similar issue, with remarkably similar numbers - ~415 requests and 45s to load the checkout. Server is not the issue and we have all merging and caches enabled, and we use Varnish (although it's probably not active on the checkout page). Did you figure anything out @Rick ?

Comment: We had a similar situation with an initial loading time of nearly 60s when going to the checkout page or refreshing it. However, it was inconsistent, so sometimes it loaded nearly instantly like the rest of the shop. This happend in developer mode only and setting the shop in production mode like suggested by @James got rid of it. Still something clearly is going wrong here as this of course shouldn't happen in developer mode...

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by switching to **production** mode, rather than developer or default, as follows:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

You can check your current application mode with:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

[The application modes are explained here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html); in my case the speed improvement with `production` was the result of it bundling Knockout components. In `developer` mode the components are all loaded individually as in OP's example, resulting in hundreds of requests.

Answer (score 1):

Bundling in Magento is meh. Don’t use it. As Sairai has already mentioned, you need to use Advanced JS Bundling. Also check that you either use Advanced Bundling or Merge JS.

Quick setup guide for Advanced Bundling. Install nodeJS, npm and Reactjs. I personally use Magento DevTools installed as a Chrome extension. There’s a record button inside the extension. Use it to record how JS loads on Checkout. I suggest you also do it for other key pages in order to create a comprehensive bundle.js file that would include other performance-critical pages.

Ok so the next step is to create static content php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

You need to go to /pub/static/frontend/Magento/yourTHEME/yourLOCALE/ let’s say /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/ Also rename en_US to en_US_source

If you have put bundle.js to Magento root folder, then you need to execute it from there:

r.js -o build.js optimize=uglify2 baseUrl=”pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US_source/” dir=”pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/”

There are more things you can do actually. We wrote [this guide](https://onilab.com/blog/magento-checkout-slow-fix-it-in-8-simple-steps/) that includes a few good ones besides advanced bundling.

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen there are lot of Js files which are  being requested from the server which slows down the  rendering process of checkout . I tried in built option of js bundling but that wasn't useless at all

After doing bit of research i found there is option to do js bundling using require js which bundles all the required js and html(knockout template files to a single js file) files after implementing this my site is rending really fast .

this js implementation is given in Mangento 2 docs - Advance js bundling
Below is the link you can follow
Jst install Nodejs and r.js on your server and use the build.js file provided -
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/samples/build.js

Below commands generates the bundles of js files which are required and after you generate the bundles you need to include those in required xml files which are mentioned in the documents

```
mv pub/static/frontend/Vendor/themename/en_US pub/static/frontend/Vendor/themename/en_US_source
r.js -o buildv1.js baseUrl=pub/static/frontend/Vendor/themename/en_US_source dir=pub/static/frontend/Vendor/themename/en_US
```

Refer the entire Article here
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html